# How to use tf.while_loop with eager execution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

In the documentation, the body of a tf.while_loop needs to be a python callable.

```
i = tf.constant(0)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i,1)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i,10)
tf.while_loop(c,b, [i])
```

works but

```
def b(i):
    tf.add(i,1)

i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i,10)
tf.while_loop(c,b, [i])
```

throws a ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type() to a Tensor

In 2.0, eager execution is default, I wonder what's the problem?!

Comment: I think your `b` function should `return` something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add return statement to your function:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def b(i):
    return tf.add(i, 1)

i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 10)
tf.while_loop(c, b, [i]) # <tf.Tensor: id=51, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=10>
```

Note that in your first example function `b` does return incremented value:

```py
i = tf.constant(0)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i,1)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i,10)
tf.while_loop(c,b, [i])
print(b(1).numpy()) # 2
```